# How can I stop the app from stopping every time I click on a button to leave the current slideshow to a new activity

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, media-player, media, eventhandler

I have a simple slideshow
with 20 slides and a 5 sec. time
delays using the
handler class, and the media
player class that plays a different
sound on each slide. There is a
button on this activity that when
you click on it at anytime, it should
stop the audio and take you  to a
new activity. 90%  of the time the
button click stops the app. 10%
of the time it stops the audio and
goes to the new activity like I want. What am I
doing wrong? Here is the code to stop the audio
and go to the next activity.

```
public void mainMenu() {
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = null;
mediaPlayer.stop();
startActivity( new         Intent(getApplicationContext(),    TableOfContents. class));
```

}

Comment: you are creating new media player and stopping your newly created media player. insted you have to stop your old media player. or post your all code of playing media player i can suggest what you shoud do

Comment: It appears that your app is throwing an Exception. Can you share the logs from the logcat. It should be in red.

Comment: Also as @AnkitaPatel mentioned, you're setting `mediaPlayer` to null, and then calling `stop()` on it. This must be throwing a `NullPointerException` which is crashing your app